How to increase vertical space between every paragraph and block by a fixed percentage?
I have a beamer frame:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,xpatch}

\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}
\definecolor{blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{HTML}{eaeff2}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=anti-flashwhite}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=fondo,fg=blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\definecolor{brightgreen}{rgb}{0.4, 1.0, 0.0}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{$\boldsymbol{\cdot}$}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
\makeatletter
\let\lemma\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
We have A.

We have B.
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have C.
\item We have D.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{lemma}
Let E hold.
\begin{itemize}
\item Then F holds.
\item Then G holds.
\end{itemize}
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


I would like to increase the vertical space between every paragraph and block in a beamer by a prescribed percentage. Above, this is the length of the red segment. This would make the content fits nicely in the frame.
Thank you very much for your elaboration.
